# Image picker crash on simulator

Tags: ios, swift

I made an app on Xcode 7.3. Today I installed XCode8 and I changed something on code then I see this crash when I hit Photo Library Button on the simulator. After this I have tried on the iPhone 6 and it works well. I have no idea why. I need to develop app but I can't. Just because of the simulator error. It's so interesting.

This is the crash screen:

[image: the crash screen]

This is my code for Photo Library:

```
@IBAction func PhotoLibraryAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary

    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func CameraAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .camera

    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    if var image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        ImageDisplay.image = image
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: You can include the image in the question btw.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to add this to your plist:

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the photo library.</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the camera.</string>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your info.plist you have to add this key `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` and put its description, check below image for reference

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this once

```
UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(chosenImage);
```